# Develop Games for IOS/Android devices?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, lua

I started learning about lua language to develop games,i percept that most people uses Corona SDK to do so.I want to know if there is another program that i don't have to pay the annual tax of $199 to build and send the app to Apple?
Is possible to develop this type in Xcode?

Comment: If you want the app on the App Store, you're going to have to send it to Apple. Because, you know, it's the _Apple_ App Store ;) Corona is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is an IDE for C, C++ and Objective variants of those languages. It has no (direct) support for Lua.

Now, you could certainly write Lua interfaces for many of the functions that an iOS application has to handle. In that way, you could then code your application in Lua and just have a small stub of C/C++/Objective-C/etc code to get your application going.

However, Corona is rather more than just a simple stub. It includes a number of frameworks that make development, not merely possible, but *easier*. If you're going to forgo Corona, you'll have to develop those frameworks yourself, either in Lua or C/C++/etc.

Comment: I know that Corona makes the development easier and its a good tool to develop apps using lua,but i heard that Apple would not accept apps wrote in lua, this is true?

Comment: @Mateus: There was some issue with a change to the EULA that would prevent using scripting languages at one point, but Apple decided to continue to allow it.

Comment: Do you if is easy to send apps developed with Corona to the Apple Store,i mean,i need to have a Corona identity and an Apple developer certificate,so i build the app with Corona and before send the app to the store!Thanks for your attention!